# How to correctly mock event handlers with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, event-handling, react-testing-library

I have a React component that takes a string and renders an audio player. This audio player has a few handlers:

`handlePlay`, `handleError`, `handleSeek`, etc.

I would like to write a few unit tests around the handlers, but I don't know what to mock. A coverage test show lines around the handlers in red - so I assume these are to be tackled, since I can't access the state to check for new values.

I got this far:

```
<button data-testid onClick={handlePlay}>Button</button>
...
const { queryByTestId } = render(<Player id="abc" />);
const button = queryByTestId("button");
fireEvent.click(button);
```

The button is being clicked, but I don't know how to test whether the handler has been called at all.

I tried to mock the handler:

```
const handlePlay = jest.fn();
handlePlay.mockImplementation(() => { console.log("works.."} );
expect(handlePlay).toBeCalled(); // or toHaveBeenCalled
```

**I get:**

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

How should I correctly mock my components very basic handlers, so I can then write some basic assertions.

*Bear in mind these handlers aren't being passed down to the component, the component only takes a string.*

Comment: Don't mock the handlers, test the behaviour of triggering the handlers. Please provide the code for the component under test.

Answer (score 2):

Any eventhandlers you define within your Player component are going to be tough to mock like that. You can spy on their side effects (e.g. console.log, new Audio(), usage of imported modules),  but the eventhandler itself is protected from the outside.

If your eventlisteners aren't too tightly coupled with your component state, consider moving the definition of them outside the component, making them reusable, open for individual unit tests, and reachable for mocking in integration tests.

Comment: is right, in this case it may be best to move the event handler callbacks out of the component and pass them back into Player as props. Something like `<Player id="abc" onClickPlay={mockHandlePlay} />`, would do the trick.

Comment: OK, but it doesn't make any sense to move handlers very related to my player outside, just to pass them down then test them.

Would it be better to maybe, if possible, just recreate the whole but a basic component as mock in my test file, with handlers, and use that?

Comment: Don't make a new component for your tests. You want to check the code that ends up in production, not write tests that only test themselves. Not to mention, you will have a confusing repo that now takes double the effort to maintain.

Nor do you have to pass your eventhandlers as props. Just define them outside the component and reference them in the component body. But it would be easier to say if you could provide some more code from the Player.